Pseudoeffectivness (or nefness) on a curve.
In a proof about varieties of higher dimension we do an induction, so we consider the case where the dimension of a variety is $n=1$. The thing is that we are supposing that some sivisor $D$ on our variety is pseudoeffective which is a numerical property. That is we need to have an intesrection product on our variety. I am fine with it for dimension at least $2$, but how should I understand pseudoeffectiveness (or nefness) in dimension $1$? Is it an empty condition, is it equivalent to effective etc ?

A divisor on a curve is pseudoeffective iff it is nef iff it has non-negative degree. It is not the same as effective, which is not a numerical condition: for example on a curve of genus at least 1, the difference of two points is numerically trivial, hence nef, but not effective.
